# Compare a $_SESSION with a variable

Tags: php

I want to compare a `$_SESSION['email_of_user']` with my variable $r.

I've got this code:

```
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE user_level = 1 ")) {

        $r = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        }
        print_r($r);
        print_r($_SESSION);


    if ($_SESSION['email_of_user'] == $r) {

/*something should happen, but it doesn't */}
```

In my print_r everything is correctly displayed and the email of `$_SESSION` is the same as the `$r`. Why is `if ($_SESSION['email_of_user'] == $r)` not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_array` fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both. So You are comparing `array` with email. you should use

```
if ($_SESSION['email_of_user'] == $r['email'])
```

Comment: It works! Thank you!! So could I possibly compare every variable in my `$r` with the Session values? F.e. : `if ($_SESSION['example_value'] == $r['examplevalue'])`

Comment: @pr0cz yes why not compare the fields which you want to authenticate.

Comment: Nice! Thanks! This helps me a lot!